# Calling a Future<Null> function from InkWell's onTap

Tags: flutter

I've created an InkWell with an onTap function call as such

```
new InkWell(onTap: _handleSelectedDate,
            ...
           )
```

Handle _handleSelectedDate is defined as a Future as the following

```
Future<Null> _handleSelectedDate(BuildContext context, AppModel model) async {
    var endYear = new DateTime.now().year + 10;
    var startYear = new DateTime.now().year - 100;
    DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: model.trackDate,
        firstDate: new DateTime(startYear, 1),
        lastDate: new DateTime(endYear));
        if (picked != null) {
           if (picked != model.trackDate) {
              model.setTrackDate(picked);
        }
}
```

}

If I call _handleSelectedDate with no parameters the call is valid, but I need to be able to pass a BuildContext and my Pages Model data through to it. As soon as I do this I get the following build error.

```
error: The argument type '(BuildContext, AppModel) → Future<Null>' 
can't be assigned to the parameter type '() → void'.
```

I'm not sure how to resolve this. I just need a way to pass data through to the call so that I can reference my Model data (I'm experimenting with scoped_model)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can wrap your call in a closure

```
new InkWell(
  onTap: () => _handleSelectedDate(context, myModel),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct way of calling a Future is

```
new InkWell(
  onTap: () async => await _handleSelectedDate(context, myModel),
)
```

Comment: Good response for future method